# font import using font-face not working on Safari

Tags: css, ios, fonts, safari, font-face

I'm using font-face on my website and it works well on all browsers but Safari.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Apfel;
font-display: swap;
src: local('Apfel'), local('Apfel-Regular'),
url("/static/assets/Apfel-Regular.woff2") format('woff2'),
url("/static/assets/Apfel-Fett.woff")  format('woff'),
url("/static/assets/Apfel-Fett.ttf")  format('truetype'); 
font-weight: 400;
}
```

Should I add another format?

Edit: After downloading Chrome on my iPhone, I noticed it's probably an issue with iOs